# Hadoop 1.2.1: Put jars in hdfs on classpath

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, classpath, gremlin

I have a hadoop job which requires several 3rd party jars. I have put them on the classpath with `conf/hadoop-env.sh`

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=hdfs://name.node.private.ip:9000/home/ec2-user/hadoop-gremlin-libs/
```

When I run `$ bin/hadoop classpath` this path is included, as you can see [here](https://pastebin.com/wh6kb87g). However, when I go to run a job, it throws an error in initialization:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.giraph.conf.AllOptions.<clinit>(AllOptions.java:37)
    at org.apache.giraph.conf.ClassConfOption.<init>(ClassConfOption.java:47)
    at org.apache.giraph.conf.ClassConfOption.create(ClassConfOption.java:60)
    at org.apache.giraph.conf.GiraphConstants.<clinit>(GiraphConstants.java:62)
    at org.apache.giraph.conf.GiraphClasses.readFromConf(GiraphClasses.java:152)
    at org.apache.giraph.conf.GiraphClasses.<init (GiraphClasses.java:142)
    at org.apache.giraph.conf.ImmutableClassesGiraphConfiguration.<init>(ImmutableClassesGiraphConfiguration.java:93)
    at org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(BspOutputFormat.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.initialize(Task.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

This particular class should be packaged in guava, which is included on the classpath:

```
[ec2-user]$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /home/ec2-user/hadoop-gremlin-libs | grep guava
-rw-r--r--   3 ec2-user supergroup          0 2017-04-20 17:57 /home/ec2-user/hadoop-gremlin-libs/guava-18.0.jar
```

I am submitting the job from gremlin as follows:

```
graph = GraphFactory.open('conf/hadoop.properties')
result = graph.compute().program(MyVertexProgram.build().create()).submit().get()
```

I have also tried putting the jars on the local filesystem and receive the same error. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Add them to the localFS....

Comment: @franklinsijo I receive the exact same error if the jars are on the local file system.

Comment: The hadoop libraries already have a `guava.jar` in them, a much older version as hadoop here is 1.2.1. Older guava jars do not have `Lists` class in them. Not an expert in classloaders, I am not entirely sure how JVM behaves in this case.

Comment: @franklinsijo I don't think that is the issue. There is no guava.jar in hadoop's lib folder.

Comment: Yea, checked the `1.2.1` version. It is not there. Can you post the output of `hadoop classpath`

Comment: the path doesn't seem to contain the local path for the gremlin libs! It still holds the HDFS path.

Comment: @franklinsijo I switched it back to the HDFS path as this small cluster will soon be large and I'd prefer to handle things via HDFS. That being said, the output of that classpath command corresponded to the local path of the libs.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what kind of job are you doing, but looking at those classes it appears to be a Mapreduce2 maptask it is trying to setup when you hit that exception.

I think you are updating the wrong classpath value probably. You are updating the Hadoop classpath not the mapreduce classpath.

More than likely you need to update the hadoop clusters yarn/mapreduce2 application classpath values in the cluster manager application, or their site xml files the cluster is using. You should have a mapred-site.xml file which has property named mapreduce.application.classpath that has its own classpath to point to its own jars it needs to execute its jobs, add your path to the classpath in the value of the mapreduce.application.classpath value instead.

The second goes for yarn, update the yarn.application.classpath property if yarn needs any other jars, as the yarn classpath points to yarn jars that help yarn run. You can update this easily in a cluster manager application if you have it, or edit the yarn-site.xml manually to add this classpath.

The only other option is if your client software program has its own dedicated mapred-site.xml file it reads to get the mapreduce.application.classpath from for you. If so it is possible you can just modify the mapreduce.application.classpath on the client site if your software supports it. Some client programs may have their own classpaths, or read the hadoop clusters site xml files to connect to the cluster.

I am pretty sure from what it shows in the exception you need this jar somehow in the mapreduce.application.path not the hadoop classpath.

Comment: That property does not exist in hadoop 1.2.1. Also, yarn was introduced in Hadoop 2. There do not seem to be any properties related to the class path in hadoop 1.2.1's mapred configuration: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred-default.html